# Using CSS to hide a class without cascading

Tags: css

Please note that I have no access to the HTML itself so I can't make any changes that way.

What I'm trying to do is hide only `.openBullet` leaving `.lowerAlpha`, `.numeral`, and `.bullet` black.

The issue I'm running into is that the transparent coloration of the marker for .openBullet is cascading down if it has children that are another marker type.

```html
<body>
  <p style="font-size: 9px; text-align: right;"><span style="color: #10265f;">Submit manual improvement suggestions <a href="mailto:IPFeedback@netjets.com">here</a>.</span></p>
  <div style="text-align: right;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 100%; border-top: hidden; border-left: hidden; border-right:hidden; border-bottom: 6px solid #007db6;">
            <p style="text-align: right;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
                alt=""></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="topic" data-documentRefId="Introduction" data-type="chapter" data-noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:fontoxml:cpa.xsd:1.0">
    <h2 data-id="id-f5cc2363-db3b-43a6-b9f9-4ff438e7faa2">1 Introduction</h2>
    <ol class="decimal" data-type="decimal" data-id="id-16c75eaf-f903-4ce9-d4ef-f6e2c8213c53">
      <li data-id="id-9dcba4f8-dae3-4751-ef37-deb3b1287c11">
        <p data-id="id-7baae131-d2fe-4e32-b3ed-824e7ee355e6">Step one goes here</p>
        <ul class="openBullet" data-type="openBullet" data-id="id-f5a5de88-dada-4089-d60e-1953caf701a4">
          <li data-id="id-d5e2366c-da46-4ee3-b044-7f2121d8e1fe">
            <p data-id="id-59bc91da-bc49-4fbc-ba22-bdb631d369fc">Open bullet</p>
            <ol class="lowerAlpha" data-type="lowerAlpha" data-id="id-b422622b-65a4-4fda-892c-ce370d851d0e">
              <li data-id="id-b609503f-a39e-4674-9ca3-15bf05ec392d">
                <p data-id="id-f051002a-9332-4254-8c0a-5be3614e8bc5">loweralpha</p>
              </li>
              <li data-id="id-1f0824e6-110b-4e7b-9979-35b3118d6b1b">
                <p data-id="id-e95c7baa-4507-43be-bfa5-acd541419bbc">loweralpha</p>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <p><br></p>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; font-size: 12px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 33.3333%;border-top: 3px solid #007db6; border-left: hidden; border-right:hidden; border-bottom: hidden;"><span style="color: #55555c;"><b>Test Manual</b></span></td>
        <td style="width: 33.3333%; text-align: center; border-top: 3px solid #007db6; border-left: hidden; border-right:hidden; border-bottom: hidden;"><strong><strong><strong><span style="color: #55555c;"> Internal Use Only</span></strong></strong>
          </strong>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 33.3333%; text-align: right; border-top: 3px solid #007db6; border-left: hidden; border-right:hidden; border-bottom: hidden;"><span style="color: #55555c;"><b>11/12/2021</b></span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

I have tried targeting .openBullet more specifically with :nth-child() but this also cascades.

Comment: You dont have acces to it but can you provide us a snippet of the html? please

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on writing questions that best enable the community to provide you with helpful direction.  There is critical context missing from this question.  Try to remember the community has no insight into your project beyond what you provide.  Can you provide a [mcve] in the question body that illustrates the issue?  It would also be helpful to clearly articulate the steps to reproduce, the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: html snippet added

Comment: I don't think that is even possible. Javascript is the only thing I know can add or remove classes dynamically. CSS just styles the HTML, either you remove the class from the HTML or use Javascript.

Comment: Are you just trying to get rid of the circular marker or are you tryiing to get rid of that whole line, including the text 'Circular marker'? If the former does list-style-type: none do what you want?

Comment: I'm trying to hide only the circular marker. So if there's a nested numerical list underneath the open bullet those numbers need to be visible. Right now I'm using this to target the circular marker but it's cascading down to children:

`[class=openBullet] li::marker{color:transparent}`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove just the circular marker without affecting subsequent numbering by setting `list-style-type: none` on the open bullet class.

```css
.openBullet {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p style="font-size: 9px; text-align: right;"><span style="color: #10265f;">Submit manual improvement suggestions <a href="mailto:IPFeedback@netjets.com">here</a>.</span></p>
  <div style="text-align: right;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 100%; border-top: hidden; border-left: hidden; border-right:hidden; border-bottom: 6px solid #007db6;">
            <p style="text-align: right;"><img src="" alt=""></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="topic" data-documentRefId="Introduction" data-type="chapter" data-noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:fontoxml:cpa.xsd:1.0">
    <h2 data-id="id-f5cc2363-db3b-43a6-b9f9-4ff438e7faa2">1 Introduction</h2>
    <ol class="decimal" data-type="decimal" data-id="id-16c75eaf-f903-4ce9-d4ef-f6e2c8213c53">
      <li data-id="id-9dcba4f8-dae3-4751-ef37-deb3b1287c11">
        <p data-id="id-7baae131-d2fe-4e32-b3ed-824e7ee355e6">Step one goes here</p>
        <ul class="openBullet" data-type="openBullet" data-id="id-f5a5de88-dada-4089-d60e-1953caf701a4">
          <li data-id="id-d5e2366c-da46-4ee3-b044-7f2121d8e1fe">
            <p data-id="id-59bc91da-bc49-4fbc-ba22-bdb631d369fc">Open bullet</p>
            <ol class="lowerAlpha" data-type="lowerAlpha" data-id="id-b422622b-65a4-4fda-892c-ce370d851d0e">
              <li data-id="id-b609503f-a39e-4674-9ca3-15bf05ec392d">
                <p data-id="id-f051002a-9332-4254-8c0a-5be3614e8bc5">loweralpha</p>
              </li>
              <li data-id="id-1f0824e6-110b-4e7b-9979-35b3118d6b1b">
                <p data-id="id-e95c7baa-4507-43be-bfa5-acd541419bbc">loweralpha</p>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <p><br></p>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; font-size: 12px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 33.3333%;border-top: 3px solid #007db6; border-left: hidden; border-right:hidden; border-bottom: hidden;"><span style="color: #55555c;"><b>Test Manual</b></span></td>
        <td style="width: 33.3333%; text-align: center; border-top: 3px solid #007db6; border-left: hidden; border-right:hidden; border-bottom: hidden;"><strong><strong><strong><span style="color: #55555c;"> Internal Use Only</span></strong></strong>
          </strong>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 33.3333%; text-align: right; border-top: 3px solid #007db6; border-left: hidden; border-right:hidden; border-bottom: hidden;"><span style="color: #55555c;"><b>11/12/2021</b></span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Note the SO snippet system did allow the copy of the complete snippet from the question as there were too many characters. I removed the contents of the img just for this demo,

Comment: Thanks! For some reason (due to how this program processes the html I'm guessing) your answer didn't quite work, but it got me in the right direction and I fixed it with `ul.openBullet{list-style-type: none}`

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused as the only time that class is used in on a ul so putting a ul there shouldn't make any difference, and it worked in the snippet.  Could you say what 'this program' that processes the HTML is? More than just a normal browser??